# In python, can I reload methods in a classes that's running?

Tags: python, irc, bots

OK, I've been creating a python IRC bot for personal use, and I'm trying to create a command that reloads a secondary parser that checks the irc data for commands to the bot (the primary parser only checks for PING, and quit/reload commands).

Is there a way to reload the code from the method whilst the class is running as an object?

Here's a link to the full code to-date (lacks a lot of commands): [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/L1nfntix)

Edit: the codes an amalgamation of lots of different things from online, and things I've been playing around with, so if you have any code optimisation (which explains the strange comments in the code), they'd be welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to change the code of an existing object in Python. You should restart the process.

People try various schemes to make it happen, but it just isn't worth it.  Just importing the module again won't work, because N imports result in the file being executed once, and all imports referring to the same module object.

If you try to subvert the `sys.modules` cache to make the import really load the file again, you still won't be changing the code that existing objects refer to.  They'll still point at the original class and methods.  New objects created after the reload will have new code, but it's very difficult to get rid of all the objects you'd created from the first load of the module.

Comment: It's not in fact *impossible*. Hackish and ill-advised, yes. But it can be done.

Comment: Consider for example the `reload()` builtin function.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: have you tried using it?  It doesn't make any attempt to change already-created objects.

Comment: That much is true. I misinterpreted "change the code of an existing object".

Comment: Thanks, I chose the simple option and just recreated the class with the updated code

Comment: But @Ned, your answer is simply wrong. It is not impossible, or even particularly complicated (see my answer). It's just not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

A program can overwrite a function or method with another:

```
def newparser(self, s):
    print s, s

myobject.parser = newparser
myobject.parser("hello") # prints "hello hello"
```

But I agree, it is not a good idea. I'm quite sure you don't *need* to do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks, I just created a new instance of the class after closing the irc connection, although your example could be useful in a different part of the program